# Clear cache Cordova build error Visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2015

When I start a new Cordova blank project, it doesn't work, I searched on stackoverflow and I reinstalled the package but still doesn't work.

[Screenshot with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXd35.jpg)

Comment: clear cache cordova and try build again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to clear cache on application startup with the code below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     // clear cache
     super.clearCache();
     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
 }
```

[Source](https://coderwall.com/p/aj79eg/adding-a-splash-screen-and-clearing-cache-with-phonegap-and-android)